# jQuery mobile listview refresh only some items

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

I'm using a listview with jQuery mobile. The listview is loaded dynamically (an Ajax function calls itself until everything is loaded or until the user clicks on stop). For each Ajax call, 100 items are added.

The more items I have, the more adding new items takes time (that does not come from the server). It seems like the culprit is this instruction:

```
 $("#ListDspQry").listview("refresh");
```

If I remove it everything's fine.

I guess the instruction processes every item of the listview, but I only need to refresh the new items. So is it possible to refresh only the 100 last items?

Here's the code:

```
//....
for (var i = this.nbDisplayed; i < this.nbRecords; i++) {
  addItem(this, i);
}
$("#ListDspQry").listview("refresh");
//....

function addItem(oSvdQuery, index) {
  var oLi = document.createElement('li');
  var oAnchor = document.createElement('a');
  var link = "javascript:showDetails(' + (index) + ')";
  oAnchor.setAttribute('href',link);
  var html='';
  var oRecord = [];
  for (i = 0; i < oSvdQuery.fields.length; i++) {
    oField = oSvdQuery.fields[i];
    oRecord = oSvdQuery.allValues[index];
    html = html + oField.name + ' : ' + oRecord[oField.name] + '<br>';
  }
  oAnchor.innerHTML = html;
  var listDspQry = document.getElementById('ListDspQry');
  listDspQry.appendChild(oLi);
  oLi.appendChild(oAnchor);
  oSvdQuery.nbDisplayed++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you can do to optimize your code and avoid the listview('refresh').

First, when adding records, instead of creating dom elements one at a time and appending each one, you can create all one hundred and append them at once.

Second, to avoid the refresh, you can just add the jQM classes directly to your elements as you add them.

For my example, I am adding 1000 records at a time. In the `for` loop, I concatenate new items to the string `allItems` and then after the `for` loop, I append all of them once. Inside the `for` loop, I add `class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r"` to the `<a>` tag so that jQM styling will be applied:

```
var index = 0;
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){

    $("#btnAdd").on("click", function(){
        var allItems = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            allItems += '<li><a href="javascript:showDetails(' + i + ')" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">item number ' + (index + i) + '</a></li>';
        }

        index += 1000;
        $("#ListDspQry").append(allItems);
    });   
});
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/yKGAc/)**

**UPDATE:**  In order to apply the `listview("refresh")` to only the added listitems and not the existing items, we can create a hidden UL in the page:

```
<div style="display: none">
    <ul id="ListTemp" data-role="listview" ></ul>
</div>
```

Then in the code, we can add the new items to the hidden UL, call `listview("refresh")`, and then detach them and append them to visible UL:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){
    $("#btnAdd").on("click", function(){
        var allItems = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            allItems += '<li><a href="javascript:showDetails(' + (index + i) + ')" >item number ' + (index + i) + '</a></li>';
        }        
        index += 100;

        $("#ListTemp").empty().append(allItems).listview("refresh");

        var element = $("#ListTemp li").detach();
        $("#ListDspQry").append(element);
    });   
});
```

> Here is an updated **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/yKGAc/6/)**

Comment: Hi. off course, it works, but i'm not very kind of this solution.First i have lot more html than that to write and if in a future release of jquerymobile the names of the class change i have to change this part. Same if i change the look (class) of the listview.

Comment: the real html i would have to write is :<li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-btn-up-c"><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="javascript:showDetails(' + (index) + ')" class="ui-link-inherit">TITLE : From Head to Toe<br></a></div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></div></li>

Comment: I don't believe you can apply .listview("refresh") to only some listitems. For the complex text you could use a templating plugin like mustache or doT.js.  Also, you could implement paging on the list so that there are never more than some practical number of items on the page at a time. Finally you could use your own CSS styled table, grid, or list instead of the standard listview widget...

Comment: i've just tested your demo. works like a charm. maybe i'll use this method.thanks

Comment: @Arsnow, see my updated answer. You can use listview('refresh') by adding new items to a hidden UL, call refresh, and then move the items to the visible one. You then don't need to manually add jQM classes.

Comment: A little hacky, but smart. unfortunately it's even slower than applying directly refresh on the original listview. i'll stick to your first solution